# POSIX compliance of the cd program?

Tags: shell, c, cd-command, posix

Is globbing and shell expansion same thing? I'm learning C by writing a [custom shell](http://github.com/montao/openshell) and I'm also learning POSIX. Now I wonder if it is POSIX compliance that `cd -` takes you back and that `~` means home directory? Because not all shells can do that, and I don't know if it is required for a minimal POSIX compliance of the cd command. The implementation I use is

```
int do_cd(int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *path;
    if (argc > 1) {
        path = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        path = getenv("HOME");
        if (path == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No HOME environment variable\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (chdir(path) < 0) {
        perror(path);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a highly ambitious way to learn C.  Might not be the most productive way, though....

Comment: I must second Wildcard. A proper shell is a very hard problem and will take you into places you never planned on going, such as turning signals on and off to protect the heap manager.

Comment: @Wildcard One is going to learn a lot more than C that way. For example you cannot write a shell without also learning a lot about how processes work.

Comment: @Wildcard Please look if you like my [question on code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/run-command-pipeline-in-c) that has more of my code.

Comment: @Joshua The signal handler works for `SIGINT`. I thought the most complicated is lexer and parser to allow non-trivial shell command pipelines e g `echo 'foo|bar'| grep -E 'foo|bar'` is an example I still can't handle yet because I tokenize at the pipeline char and the pipeline char can have at least three different meanings, where I should leave the meaning to the program if the pipeline char is inside a well-matched expression.

Comment: @Programmer400 In that example `'foo|bar'` would have to be a token by itself.

Comment: @Programmer400 Tokenise as you go, and have two (three?) different modes: one normal mode, and one (two?) string modes.

Comment: @Programmer400: What happens if you get a SIGINT in the middle of malloc?

Comment: @Joshua I never thought of that before. I'm new to this detailed C programming (coming from Java and Python). I'm also writing a custom malloc that can take care of a SIGINT when doing malloc _maybe_ but the malloc isn't done. You may have a look at [Joel's malloc implementation](https://github.com/joelpet/malloc) and see if that can handle a SIGINT.

Comment: @Programmer400: The odds of any random malloc handling what the shell needs to do in its SIGINT handler (that is, return from the shell command processes back to the command line) approaches NIL. I can prove that no multithreaded version exists.

Comment: @Joshua Then what do you think if my shell comes with a custom malloc that handles it, if it is even possible? Not all computer science is possible. But we have a malloc that we can change.

Comment: Then I think you've known assembly for years. I think its possible for single threaded, but I think C doesn't provide the primitives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) is part of shell command processing, not part of `cd`. `cd` sees the already-expanded path as its argument.

POSIX [requires `cd -` to be equivalent to `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_05). `OLDPWD` [must be set by `cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_03) if `PWD` exists at the time of running the command.

Comment: It seems that `sash` doesn't do tilde expansion.

Comment: @Programmer400, ...then `sash` isn't a POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: sash doesn't do tilde expansion because sash expects to run from a rescue environment.

Answer (score 2):

Tilde expansion seems to be standardized (cf. [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_01)), but is part of the shell expansion, not of
`cd`.

`cd -` must also be supported (cf. [IEEE Std 1003.1,2005](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cd.html)).

Comment: I'm not sure what shell expansion is, is that the same as globbing e g `ls *.c *.h|grep -E main` ? Is shell expansion, quoting and wildcards and globbing 3 distinct?

Comment: @Programmer400 On [the first image here](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html) there are several "shell expansions" between steps 4 and 10. Globbing is an alternate name for specifically "Pathname expansion".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [cd -](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) is POSIX mandated:  and so is [tilda expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)  (all it takes is a little of web searching ;-))

Your `cd` builtin (technically not a "program") will need to do some option parsing too if it wants to be POSIX compliant.

As for globbing vs shell expansion, the way I understand it, globbing is a particular case of shell expansion that involves a specific type of pattern matching.